# ReactJs, Data only loads when I clicked on the accordion header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zendesk

This is my App.js

`console.log(customer)` shows the data on the console here, so I think there is no problem on my  API.

```
    let client = null;
    let customer_id = null;
    var customer = null;
    
    const getCustomerId = () => {
    
        client.get('ticket.requester.id').then(
            function(data) {
                customer_id = data['ticket.requester.id'].toString();
            }
        );
    
        var settings = {
            url:'/api/sunshine/objects/records?type=Customer',
            type:'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
        
        };
        
        client.request(settings).then(
            function(data) {
                var jsonCount = Object.keys(data.data).length;
                var x = 0;
                console.log(customer_id);
                while(x < jsonCount) {
                    var cust = data.data[x];
                    if (cust.attributes.CustomerID == customer_id) {
                        customer = data.data[x];
                        // console.log(customer);
                    }
                    x = x + 1;
                }
                console.log(customer);
            },
            function(response) {
                console.error(response.responseText);
            }
        );
    }
    
    
    const App = () => {
    
        const [expandedSections, setExpandedSections] = useState([]);
        const [expandedSections2, setExpandedSections2] = useState([]);
        useEffect(() => {
            client = window.ZAFClient.init();
            getCustomerId();
       }, []);
    
   return (
    <Row justifyContent="center">
        <Col className="outer_column">
    
            <Accordion className="first_accordion"
                level={2}
                expandedSections={expandedSections}
                onChange={index => {
                if (expandedSections.includes(index)) {
            setExpandedSections(expandedSections.filter(n => n !== index));
                    } else {
                        setExpandedSections([index]);
                    }
                    }}
                    >
                    <Accordion.Section>
    
                    <Accordion.Header>
                    <Accordion.Label>Customer Management</Accordion.Label>
                        </Accordion.Header>
                        <Accordion.Panel>
                            <Row justifyContent="center">
                                <Col className="inner_column">
                                    <Accordion
                                        isCompact
                                        level={5}
                                        isExpandable
                                        className="second_accordion"
                                            >
                                        <Accordion.Section>
                                            <Accordion.Header>
                <Accordion.Label>Customer Information</Accordion.Label>
                                    </Accordion.Header>
                    <Accordion.Panel className="accordion_panel">
    
                    <Display jsonData = {JsonData} tryData = {customer}/>
    
                                                </Accordion.Panel>
                                            </Accordion.Section>
                                        </Accordion>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </Accordion.Panel>
                        </Accordion.Section>
                    </Accordion>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        )
    }
    
    export default App;
```

This is my Display.js:

```
    function withMyHook(Component) {
  return function WrappedComponent(props) {
    const myHookValue = useZafClient();
    return <Component {...props} myHookValue={myHookValue} />;
  }
}

class Display extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      fields: this.props.jsonData.data[0].attributes,
      errors: {},
      customers: [],
      flag: (this.props.jsonData.data[0].attributes.CustomerID === "") ? 'register' : 'view' 
    };
  }

  handleChange(field, e) {
    let fields = this.state.fields;
    fields[field] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ fields });
  }

  render() {
    console.log("trydata");
    console.log(this.props.tryData);
    return(
      <div>
          {Object.keys(this.props.jsonData.data[0].attributes).map((key, i) => (
            <p key={i}>
              <span>{key}
                <input value={this.state.fields[key] || ''} 
                    placeholder={key}
                    disabled = {(this.state.flag === 'view') ? "disabled" : "" }
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,key)} /></span>
            </p>
          ))}

          {(this.state.flag === "register") ? 
          <Button onClick={() => this.setState({flag: 'view'})}> Register </Button> :
          null
          }

          {(this.state.flag === "view") ? 
          <Button onClick={() => this.setState({flag: 'update'})}> Edit </Button> :
          null
          }

          {(this.state.flag === "update") ? 
          <Button onClick={() => this.setState({flag: 'view'})}> Submit </Button> :
          null
          }
      </div>
    )
  }
};

export default withMyHook(Display);
```

As you can see.. the API call on my App.js is being passed through `tryData = {customer}`, my problem is the data won't be pass to Display.js, not until I open the `Accordion Customer Information`.. you can see on the display.js that I am using `this.props.jsonData.data[0].attributes` instead of `this.props.tryData.attributes`, because I get type error [Props error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao31Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

## Try to put variables inside of the App component that you pass as a props value

```
  const App =()=>
{
  let client=null,
  ....
}
```